# How import libraries from another android project

Tags: android

I have downloaded an example android project and was able to run into.

Now I want to integrate the functionality of that example into my own app. The example app uses api from a private library Jar file.

I want to know what the proper way is to copy this library into my project. I prefer not to reference, but make it part of my project such that I can delete the example project.

Obviously dragging the library into my project occurred to me, but not sure if this is the right way to do it.

[Update] heres is the example project I need to integrate into my app. Are there other things I need to copy over besides just the opentok-android-sdk.jar, such as the x86 folder?

[image]

Comment: Right click opentok-android-sdk.jar and select add to build path should do the trick.

Comment: the is no "add to build path" option when I right click on the jar file.

Comment: Try this then, Right click the project itself then got Java Build Path > Libraries (Your jar should be here if its not then select add jar)

Answer (score 1):

You can just copy the `jar` file into your `libs` directory.

Comment: actually this didnt work. I was able to compile, but when I try to run the code that uses the library, I get an unsatisfied link error.

Comment: It seems that opentok-android-sdk.jar depends on the native binary files in armeabi, armeabi-v7a, mips and x86 directories. Copy those directories as well.

Comment: This answer is not correct. simply copying the Jar files does not do the job.